# Call Tree section in Instruments is disabled (greyed out)

Tags: iphone, xcode, instruments

I know this should be enabled but I'm not sure why it isnt. I've tried with multiple apps but it doesn't change its state.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

[Instruments Call Tree Disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGy5M.png)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have to be in the call tree view to have the Call Tree section enabled. Instruments doesn't initially show the call tree view so you have to switch to it manually. Use the jump bar to switch to the call tree view.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem!